# scala xml rewrite rule (or, simple pattern help)

Tags: xml, scala

I'm missing some fairly simple syntax I gather.  I'm trying to rewrite an element label to something else and keep everything else intact.

```
object htmlRule extends RewriteRule {
 override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] = n match {
   case Elem(prefix, "document", attribs, scope, child@_*)  =>
     Elem(prefix, "html", attribs, scope, child)
   case other => other
 }
}
```

Now, I ask for an explanation of two things:

1) What exactly does "child@_*" mean in plain English?

2) How can I capture the value of "child@_*" and just let it pass right through to the new element?  Currently, I get the following error, which makes sense.

```
[error]  found   : Seq[scala.xml.Node]
[error]  required: scala.xml.Node
[error]       Elem(prefix, "html", attribs, scope, child)
```

I'm not wedded to this either, so if there's a better way to simply change the element name of a specific node, let's here it...

Thanks,
--tim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation:

```
case ... bindVar @ patternConstraint ... => /* bindVar is bound to what patternConstraint matched here */
```

Allows you to match "within" a value (the patternConstraint part) while capturing the overall value subjected to that constraint (as bindVar).

In your particular case, `child @ _*`, the `_` means "don't care", the `*` means a sequence of values and `child @` means bind child to the entire sequence.

A frequent use of this capability is a nested pattern (usually mentioning case classes):

```
case expr @ Expr(op, lhs, rhs) => // Do stuff with expr, op, lhs and rhs
```

Here, the target of the match is tested to see if it is an instance of `Expr` and if it is, `op` is bound to the `Expr`'s operator, `lhs` and `rhs` are bound to its left- and right-hand sides, resp. and `expr` is bound to the Expr instance itself.

Comment: Thanks Randall,
Can you explain the weirdness that it matches an Elem with a node sequence _* but yet, the Elem constructor doesn't take a node sequence?  First, is that correct?  Second, if so, what's the way to achieve my desired behavior?  Thanks for you detailed binding explanation:)

Comment: Use child:_* to apply the Seq[Node] as the Node* vararg parameter.

Comment: Thanks Silvio, I'm still unsure exactly why this magical syntax works but it does.  Clearly I have a whole new area of Scala learning to do:)

Answer (score 1):

`Elem` is not a case class, it is an "ordinary" class with a companion object. There is a way to write ordinary (non-case) classes to simulate case classes. But more typically one views case classes as a shorthand for writing a bunch of boilerplate code, some of it in the class and some of it in an implicitly created companion. In this case, the pertinent bits are the `unapply` and / or `unapplySeq` methods in the companion object. These methods are what make non-case classes amenable to pattern matching.

For `Elem` the pertinent matching "signature" is that of `object scala.xml.Elem#unapplySeq(...)`, specifically:

```
def unapplySeq(n: Node): Option[(String, String, MetaData, NamespaceBinding, Seq[Node])]
```

There you can see the pattern of bindings created when matching with `Elem`. They do in fact correspond to the pattern you're using in your sample code.